# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < With $.jsonp and webservices

Tags: jquery, xml, web-services, jsonp

I was able to fix my webservice ajax issue with a jquery plugin. called jquery.jsonp.js.   now on my success function i am getting a Uncaught

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

error on the chrome console window.  I have tried various ways to fix this but I am at a loss

```
$.jsonp({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:49524/mobile/Android/AndroidWebServices.asmx/CheckLogin",
    data: "email="+u+"&password="+p,
    crossDomain:true,
    success: function (data) {
        var s = $(data).find('string').text();;
        alert(s);
    }
});
```

if there is a better way to get the value from the xml i would greatly appreciate any help

```
<string xmlns="http://wmstec.com/">true</string>
```

is the XML file that is returned from the webservice

```
 [WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string CheckLogin(string email, string password)
{

    string vid = "xxxx";

    //Get the User Information
    DB.User cur_user = DB.User.ByEmail(email.Trim());
    //if it failed, try by screen name
    if (-1 == cur_user.ID) { cur_user = DB.User.ByScreenName(email.ToLower()); }


    //Does their password match?

   if (cur_user.CheckPassword(password, vid))
    {
    // companys ToJSON function 
       return Utility.ToJSON("true");
    }
    else
    {
        return Utility.ToJSON(return "false");
    }
}
```

UPDATE

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:49524/mobile/Android/AndroidWebServices.asmx/CheckLogin",
    crossDomain:true,
    data: "email="+u+"&password="+p,//({ email: u, password: p}),
    dataType :"jsonp",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success : function(data){
        alert(data);}

});
```

returns the same thing.. so its not necessarily the jsonp plugin that is an issue.. its obviously a user issue lol..

Comment: So, you're requesting JSONP but returning XML?  That sounds like your issue.

Comment: Most likely your webservice is returning XML rather than JSONP. If you want to use JSONP, your webservice must return JSONP. JSONP is JSON wrapped in a callback() so that it can be executed as an external script. JSON is a data format similar to XML, but it's syntax is very different and closely mimics the syntax of a javascript object literal.

Comment: @KevinB: JSONP doesn't *have* to be a JavaScript object (not actually JSON).  It usually is, but it can be anything as long as it's wrapped in a function call.

Comment: ***Please note***: `contentType` is the content type of the **request** sent ***to*** the server, *not* that of the response sent from the server.

Answer (score 2):

`jquery.jsonp.js` is a library for accessing data expressed in JSON-P over HTTP.

`<string xmlns="http://wmstec.com/">true</string>` is data expressed as XML, not JSON-P (JSON-P consists of an `application/javascript` program consisting of a single function call (to a function you define) with the service's data as an argument to that call).

You will need to change the web service so it outputs JSON-P if you want to use this approach.

Comment: how can I change the output to be JSONp then? I'll edit my question with the webservices

Comment: @DWolf: I don't know how the JSONP plugin you're using works, but usually a `calllback` parameter is added to the GET string.  You need to echo your data wrapped in that function call.  Such as: `http://yourservice.com/jsonp?callback=test123`, then you'd echo `test123({your: 'data'});`.